# BCrypt is not allowed for Windows Store Apps

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, windows-store, bcrypt.net

I'm using Bcrypt.net hashing for passwords in Windows Store App. It works fine when built and tested in windows tablets. But when I'm trying to upload this app to store it fails in supported API test.

Following error details is given

API System.ApplicationException in MSCORLIB, PUBLICKEYTOKEN=B77A5C561934E089 is not supported for this application type. BCrypt.Net.dll calls this API.

```
API System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo in MSCORLIB, PUBLICKEYTOKEN=B77A5C561934E089 is not supported for this application type. BCrypt.Net.dll calls this API.
API System.Security.Cryptography.RandomNumberGenerator in MSCORLIB, PUBLICKEYTOKEN=B77A5C561934E089 is not supported for this application type. BCrypt.Net.dll calls this API.
API System.ApplicationException.#ctor in MSCORLIB, PUBLICKEYTOKEN=B77A5C561934E089 is not supported for this application type. BCrypt.Net.dll calls this API.
API System.ApplicationException.#ctor(System.String) in MSCORLIB, PUBLICKEYTOKEN=B77A5C561934E089 is not supported for this application type. BCrypt.Net.dll calls this API.
API System.ApplicationException.#ctor(System.String,System.Exception) in MSCORLIB, PUBLICKEYTOKEN=B77A5C561934E089 is not supported for this application type. BCrypt.Net.dll calls this API.
API System.ApplicationException.#ctor(System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo,System.Runtime.Serialization.StreamingContext) in MSCORLIB, PUBLICKEYTOKEN=B77A5C561934E089 is not supported for this application type. BCrypt.Net.dll calls this API.
API System.Text.StringBuilder.AppendFormat(System.String,System.Object) in MSCORLIB, PUBLICKEYTOKEN=B77A5C561934E089 is not supported for this application type. BCrypt.Net.dll calls this API.
API System.Security.Cryptography.RandomNumberGenerator.Create in MSCORLIB, PUBLICKEYTOKEN=B77A5C561934E089 is not supported for this application type. BCrypt.Net.dll calls this API.
API System.Security.Cryptography.RandomNumberGenerator.GetBytes(System.Byte[]) in MSCORLIB, PUBLICKEYTOKEN=B77A5C561934E089 is not supported for this application type. BCrypt.Net.dll calls this API.
```

What can be done for this? Any ideas?
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: The question in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14069739/password-hashing-in-windows-store-app may give you relevant pointers.

Comment: Are you sure you are using winrt version for dll

Comment: It seems that PBKDF2 is supplied: [KeyDerivationAlgorithmProvider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.security.cryptography.core.keyderivationalgorithmprovider.algorithmname.aspx) (if it is part of the store API) which is a good alternate to BCrypt().

Answer (score 2):

As the error message stated

> API System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo in MSCORLIB,
>   PUBLICKEYTOKEN=B77A5C561934E089 is not supported for this application
>   type. BCrypt.Net.dll calls this API.

The SerializationInfo class does not belong to [.NET for Store App](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh454059.aspx).

You can not use BCrypt.NET in store app development because it is build on full .NET, I recommend you using [HashAlgorithmProvider class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.security.cryptography.core.hashalgorithmprovider.aspx) in Windows Runtime App.

Comment: It is for an app where security is THE main concern. If I'm to use HashAlgorithmProvider class, then I must go for SHA512. But SHA512 is not good enough as per [this article] (http://codahale.com/how-to-safely-store-a-password/)

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a bit late to the party but I have ported BCrypt.net to .net Core, so you should be able to use it now. Just swap out your dependency to the one here:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/BCrypt.Net-Core/

It should be a drop in replacement.

Comment: Thanks Kushan. We will try it out.

Comment: @NoviceProgrammer if you have any issues, do let me know and I will try to resolve them